# DB2 Query Functions Not Working With Parameters

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a query that I can't get to work in DB2/AS400.

```
select integer(score(ADRLIN1, :param1)*100) as RELEVANCEADR, 
ADRLIN1, PSTCOD from MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE 
where contains(ADRLIN1, :param2) = 1
and pstcod like :param3 
order by RELEVANCEADR desc
```

When I try to run the query above, and entering values in my parameters, I get [SQL0418] Use of parameter marker not valid.

This isn't a big issue. A google search told me to CAST the parameters prior to using them. So then I change the query to this:

```
select integer(score(ADRLIN1, CAST(:param1 AS CHAR))*100) as RELEVANCEADR, 
ADRLIN1, PSTCOD from MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE  
where contains(ADRLIN1, CAST(:param2 AS CHAR)) = 1
and pstcod like :param3 order by RELEVANCEADR desc
```

With the following values:

- param1 --> 19 EDGEWOOD BLVD
- param2 --> 19 EDGEWOOD BLVD
- param3 --> %68046%

And I get an empty resultset. **However**, if I actually fill in the query with literals, the query works.

```
select integer(score(ADRLIN1, '19 EDGEWOOD BLVD')*100) as RELEVANCEADR, 
ADRLIN1, PSTCOD from MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
where contains(ADRLIN1, '19 EDGEWOOD BLVD') = 1
and pstcod like '%68046%' 
order by RELEVANCEADR desc
```

The query above returns a valid record.

My question is, how can I get the score and contains functions to work with passed in parameters instead of using hard-coded strings?

Comment: You have `param1` and `param2` in your code.  Are you passing the same string for both?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, even if I replace the `param2` to be `param1` to ensure the same string is passed, the resultset is empty.

Comment: `CHAR` is equivalent to `CHAR(1)`, so all your input values are truncated. Use the actual data type when casting.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I changed CHAR to CHAR(50) and it worked!

Comment: One other thing that could bite you if `param3` is defined as `CHAR` vs. `VARCHAR` is that a `CHAR' variable is always the defined length, andc pads on the left with blanks. So if you put `%68046%` in a CHAR(10) field, it is as if you used `'%68046%   '` and will only find rows where `pstcod` contains 68046 `and` has three blanks at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mustaccio pointed out in the comments, casting as a `CHAR` is the equivalent to `CHAR(1)`. I corrected this to declare an actual length and the query is working.